# How to set name file as variable in c++?

Tags: c++

How to set "dt" variable as file name?

```
time_t now = time(0);
string dt = ctime(&now);


ofstream file;
file.open( ??? );
```

I'm trying to set dt as the name

Comment: And what is the name of the file you'd like to open?

Comment: Have you tried just doing `file.open(dt);` ?

Comment: @YSC dt (this is system time)

Comment: You probably want to add an extention to the file before you open it (like.txt)  `dt += ".txt";`.

Answer (score 4):

Since C++11 you can simply pass the `string` as argument: `file.open(dt);`.

Before that you have to pass a `const char*` as argument: `file.open(dt.c_str());`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open

You can also use the constructor directly: `ofstream file(dt);` or `ofstream file(dt.c_str());` before C++11.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream

Comment: nothing happens when i do that

Comment: @lolorek What do you expect? You're doing nothing in your code with this file

Comment: @lolorek Have you checked the stream status (e.g. `if (!file)`) to see if something went wrong? And how do you notice that "nothing happens"? Are you checking for the file in the correct directory?